# C++ fstream writing on a batch file, then ends without the rest of the lines of codes

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd, fstream

I'm currently working on this code that would create a batch file with the command to ping a certain IP address. I want it to execute the batch file and log the results to a txt file. For some reason, however, it stops(?) after the pinging. It does make the txt file, but it doesn't display anything about it. It also would ignore the next following lines of codes.

I've tried merging the two "bat <<"s but it's the same thing. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string results;
    ofstream bat;
    ifstream text ("bat.txt");
    bat.open ("bat.bat");
    bat << "@echo off \n ping 216.52.241.254 \n ";
    bat << "bat.bat > bat.txt";
    bat.close();
    system("bat.bat");
    bat.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Then the console would only show

```
Pinging 216.52.241.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.52.241.254: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=245
Reply from 216.52.241.254: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=245
Reply from 216.52.241.254: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=245 
Reply from 216.52.241.254: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=245

Ping statistics for 216.52.241.254:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 62ms, Maximum = 63ms, Average = 62ms
```

Then it stops after that with the blinking cursor, doesn't even return 0.

So basically I want to ping this IP, then the results would copy to a txt file, so that the same program could read the txt file and show the average ping time. Problem is, it ends abruptly after the ping. Any ideas on how to fix this? Really hoping for an answer. Been working on this for hours researching and trying different approaches until I have no choice but to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream bat;
    bat.open ("bat.bat");
    bat << "@echo off" << endl;
    bat << "ping 216.52.241.254" << endl;
    bat.close();
    system("cmd /K bat.bat > ping_output.log");
    return 0;
}
```

try using this method, if it says bat.bat does not exist try opening in current working directory